# Amcharts - Change value axis properties dynamically

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I have a StackedBarChart which shows serveral values per day. Now i want to switch the view from absolute values to relative values. Therefore i need to change the valueAxis properties like

```
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 100;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
valueAxis.calculateTotals = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 50;
```

But how can i get the valueAxis from an existing chart object?

Comment: Do you mean like `chart.xAxes` or `chart.xAxes._values[0].properties`? In my experience it is easier to dispose and recreate charts tho, depending on your implementation.

Comment: @Lain - don't use the underscored variables as they are internal/"private" and are managed by the chart object. Use the [List methods](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/) such as `getIndex` to get access to the objects you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your axis object by accessing it from the [`xAxes`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#xAxes) or [`yAxes`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#yAxes) [list](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/), depending on where you assigned the object to, and use `getIndex` or loop through them using `each` if you have multiple axes you want to update.

```
// assuming you have one value axis on the y axis:
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.getIndex(0);
// make updates to the variable

// if you have multiple value axes:
chart.yAxes.each(function(valueAxis) {
  // make changes to each axis object
});
```